# Batch update works as set operation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I need to do a batch update with Firebase's real-time database. I have done it like so:

This is working fine. But I need an update only for the 2nd operation. At this moment it works as `set` operation. Any clue?

```
 const updates = {}; //batch operation

   // this is working fine and I need it as set operation
    updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/leads/${lead.id.toString()}`] = {
      name: lead.name,
      address: lead.address,
    };

    // But problem is here. I need to write it as update operation
    updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/addresses/${lead.id.toString()}`] = {
      address: lead.address,
     };

    return this.angularFireDatabase.object('/').update(updates);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multi-path update functions as a `set` on each individual key in the map that you pass in. Since you pass in `groups/${this.groupId}/addresses/${lead.id.toString()}` as the key, it *sets* the value you specify on that path.

If you only want to update the `address` property under that path, include the `address` key in the path, instead of in the value:

```
updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/addresses/${lead.id.toString()}/address`] = lead.address;
```